MP4 video in powerpoint only plays the second time (or third...)
I have a macOS PowerPoint presentation with inserted MP4 videos. When I first switch to a slide (either in slide editing or slide show mode) the first time I play a video it plays for the duration of the video but is stuck on the first frame for the entire playback.
The second (or subsequent) times I play the video it works fine and advances through all the frames. If I switch out of and go back to a slide with a video the playback issue happens again.
The videos play the first time in VLC and QuickTime.
System and software details:

MacBook Pro, Nov 2023, Chip: Apple M3 Pro, built-in GPU.
macOS: Sonoma 14.7
Powerpoint: Version 16.89.1 (24091630)

I am confident I have removed and tried all permutations of relevant animations. And have tried the various options for video 'Playback' in the top ribbon.

What are the file sizes of the videos? Have you updated PowerPoint to the latest version? With Sonoma being only a week old, perhaps there's some bad mojo between PP and Sonoma. Can you test to see if this occurs on a Mac with an earlier version of macOS?

Thanks for your questions. The problem videos are about 5 seconds in duration. Longer videos (>10 seconds) start the first time. The same issue occurred before updating to Sonoma and I just checked PowerPoint for updates.
